# pandas assigns column name randomly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I extracted some dates and temperature values from an `xml` file and wanted to make a dataframe out of them. So after some loops I defined variable `temperature` and `date` and appended their values to a list out of the loop (`placeholder`). Later I made a DataFrame from them and assigned the column name directly while making the dataframe. But I relaized that with every time I run my code the column names get assigned right or wrong randomly.
Here is my code:

```
placeholder=[]
for timeserie in timeseries:
    date = re.findall('<entryisIntraday\D*(\d*.\d*.\d*)', timeserie)
    temperature = re.findall('<value>(.*)<\/value>', timeserie)[0]
    placeholder.append([date, temperature])
print(placeholder)
df = pd.DataFrame(placeholder, columns= {"DATE", "TEMP"})
print(df)
```

after running the code sometimes the result is like this:

```
[['2019-10-29', '4.4'], ['2019-10-30', '3.6'], ['2019-10-31', '2.1'] ...
          TEMP                DATE
0   2019-10-29                 4.4
1   2019-10-30                 3.6
2   2019-10-31                 2.1
```

and sometimes like this:

```
[['2019-10-29', '4.4'], ['2019-10-30', '3.6'], ['2019-10-31', '2.1'], ...
          DATE                TEMP
0   2019-10-29                 4.4
1   2019-10-30                 3.6
2   2019-10-31                 2.1
```

I didn't had this problem when I assigned the column names after I built the DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(placeholder)
df=df.rename(columns= {0:"DATE",1:"TEMP"})
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `columns` argument of [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor should be a `list`, not a `set`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(placeholder, columns = ["DATE", "TEMP"])
```

Comment: You are right, I didn't see that. But why do we see that behaviour from pandas when we put the names in a set?

Comment: A `set` object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set). So order is not guaranteed.